# Как сделать так, чтоб когда создаю класс вместо Cat.Gender.Male было Gender.Male

Tags: c#, классы, enum

```
public class Cat
{
    public enum Gender { Male, Female }
    public Cat(string name, Gender gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public Gender gender { get; }
```

Создаю елемент класса

```
var faradayTheCat = new Cat("Faraday", Cat.Gender.Male);
```

Суть вопроса в том, чтобы создать элемент класса таким примером:

```
var faradayTheCat = new Cat("Faraday", Gender.Male);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Значит вам нужно вынести перечисление из класса.

```
public enum Gender { Male, Female }


public class Cat
{

    public Cat(string name, Gender gender)
    {
        Name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public Gender gender { get; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще псевдоним прописать через using, но не уверен, что это правила хорошего тона:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using TestEnum= TestProj.Program.Test.TestEnum;

namespace TestProj
{
    class Program
    {

       public class Test
        {
            public enum TestEnum
            {
                val1,val2
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = TestEnum.val1;
        }
    }
}
```